# Всплывающий блок на определённое время

Tags: javascript, css

Можно ли реализовать функцию всплывающего блока как на сайте ВКонтакте после добавления друга (например).

То есть, в углу страницы плавно появляется сообщение, и автоматически скрывается через несколько секунд. И появление должно быть по условию, если выбрали один chekbox, то оно появляется с одним сообщением, если другой, то соответственно с другим.

Причём плавность не обязательна, главное как таймер установить?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть очень хорошая штука на jquery [Плагин jQuery Timers](http://www.linkexchanger.su/2008/71.html)